# Keyboard not working in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, 20.04, thinkpad, xserver

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad, and initially had the 18.04 Ubuntu installed. Two days back my keyboard stopped functioning, all except the top first row. In many forums people who had similar problem tried to install the latest version of xserver-xorg, but this did not work for me. After a while I thought the problem might get fixed of I upgraded to 20.04 and tried this today. This also failed. Would be very grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Have seen questions with the whole keyboard or just a few keys(2 or 3).  Would try a Live Ubuntu USB and/or another keyboard, but think this is a hardware problem.  Would adjust your question to mention exact row, top or bottom.

Comment: Did do the change that you suggested, thank you. Is there a way to know whether it is a hardware problem for sure, cause replacing a keyboard costs a lot.

Comment: I meant a USB or wireless keyboard.  Here are a couple of links,  https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht103985/  https://superuser.com/questions/80199/my-3-e-d-c-keys-stopped-working-on-my-laptop